# Perform Gray Addition

Tags: code-golf

## Objective

Given two non-negative integers encoded in unbounded-length [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), add them and output the result, where the result is also encoded in Gray code.

## Gray code

There are many equivalent formulations of Gray code, but here's an intuitive one.

The Gray code encodes each non-negative integer as an infinite bit-string. Starting from encoding zero, as the enumeration goes, the least significant bit keeps cycling through `"0110"`. Each place of bit keeps cycling through what the previously significant bit cycles through, but doubled entry-wise. To summarize:

```
0th LSB: Cycles through "0110"
1st LSB: Cycles through "00111100"
2nd LSB: Cycles through "0000111111110000"
3rd LSB: Cycles through "00000000111111111111111100000000"
(And so on)
```

That gives the encodings of few non-negative integers as:

```
Integer = Gray code
("..." stands for infinitely many leading zeroes)
0 = "...00000"
1 = "...00001"
2 = "...00011"
3 = "...00010"
4 = "...00110"
5 = "...00111"
6 = "...00101"
7 = "...00100"
8 = "...01100"
9 = "...01101"
```

Note that, for each pair of integers differing by one, their Gray codes differ by only one bit.

## I/O format

Flexible. Standard loopholes apply.

## Examples

Here, inputs and outputs are Gray codes with their leading zeroes stripped off.

```
"" + "" = ""
"1" + "1" = "11"
"1" + "10" = "110"
"10" + "1" = "110"
"10" + "11" = "111"
"111" + "111" = "1111"
```

Comment: This is [A268719](https://oeis.org/A268719).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
^\€ḄSH^$B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8u5lHTmoc7WoI94lSc/j/cuc/6UcMcBV07hUcNc60PtwMFVLgOtwPVRP7/Hx0dbRCrowAkQGS0IYg0RGbrKMCkQCwkWRhXRwEhAuZABcHisQA)

A monadic link taking a pair of lists of binary digits as its argument and returning a list of binary digits. Expects the Gray coding with all leading zeros removed other than for zero itself; returns a Gray coded number in the same format.

### Explanation

```
^\€       | Reduce each by xor, collecting up intermediate results
   Ḅ      | Convert from binary
    S     | Sum
     H^$  | Xor with half
        B | Convert to binary digits
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>(t=e(a)+e(b))^t/2
e=t=>t&&t^e(t>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcyxCoNAEITh3geRXUKMZ7/7EumFO7OKQW6DDnn9SzBdUhgYpvr47/EZt2GdHzhnv1kZpUTRJEoQo8gno8Tc49JVJhBFXaM3gmrgMnjefLFm8YlGavm9Bn7FOueJOubqC6TA@/2DDlPtzg5j4ZP7geUF)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€ηOÉJCOD;^b
```

Port of [*@NickKennedy*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267311/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

Input as a pair of lists of binary digits without leading 0s (where `0` could be either `[0]` or `[]`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOac9v9D3d6Ofu7WMcl/f8fHW2oYxCrAyQNY2MB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/R01rzm33P9zp5ezvYh2X9F/nf3R0dKxOdCwQRxsACQMwyxBIGCJYOlBRHQOEOIStA@OBWDpQOjYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
€            # Map over each inner list of the (implicit) input-pair:
 η           #  Get its prefixes
  O          # Sum each inner prefix-list
   É         # Check for each sum whether it's odd
    J        # Join each inner list of binary digits together to a string
     C       # Convert each from a binary-string to a base-10 integer
      O      # Sum the pair together
       D;    # Push a copy of this sum, and halve it
         ^   # Bitwise-XOR the sum and halved sum together
             # (where both are treated as floored integers, ignoring any `.5` decimals)
          b  # Convert this from a base-10 integer to a binary-string
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
≔⍘ΣＥＥ²Ｓ↨²Ｅι﹪Σ…ι⊕μ²¦²θ⭆θ¬⁼ι§⁺0θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEX3niK4mkAK6taVlS6ysAieIMSg0pioSUp7@tRJXQwf/p/35CwOaYWOsXFumQzchVODPxYzwRBW6MSWrmKEmy34a6KUEfzEHuflDDsGbRPUfqVW7WxTz4081KqMVyOsFMGK0isZ2Wmd9afSw9@Msp2Rp/Xw2IPQDhWN52ZUH@h1cJAXOWKMvJKmjrEsiqws4@2tfw) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses bit strings for I/O. Explanation: Somewhat limited by the lack of a bitwise XOR function.

```
≔⍘ΣＥＥ²Ｓ↨²Ｅι﹪Σ…ι⊕μ²¦²θ
```

For each input, get all of its prefixes, take the digit sum modulo `2`, and interpret the results as base `2`. Then convert the sum back to base `2`.

```
⭆θ¬⁼ι§⁺0θκ
```

Compare each bit with the previous and output `0` if they the same and `1` if they differ.